# Is there a way to use a model field in an if conditional via a Django Template?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am creating a template that displays a button but only if a particular user has a 'path' field in the Model. How can I use the model attribute inside the if conditional?

This is my current code:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Path(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    path = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank=False, null=False)   #Will not accept empty string or None 
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"
```

template.html:

```
{% if request.user.path.path %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="function()" id='button'> Initiate Index </button>
{% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "function()" id = 'abort_button'> Initiate Index </button>
{% endif %}
```

jquery in template.html:

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#button").click(function() {  #If path is available
          alert('Thank you...');
        });

        $("#abort_button").click(function() {  #If path is not available
            alert('Please insert path');
        });
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since blank=False, null=False is added to path field, every path object will have a non empty path field.  right?

Comment: Yes. But my intention was to show a button (if available) that alerts 'thank you'. Or, alert "Please add a path" if it isn't available in the database. I have updated the question again, please do have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Path` model has `OneToOne` relation with the `User` model you can check whether the the currently logged in user has path field or not like this in your template

```
{% if request.user.path.path %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="function()" id='button'> Initiate Index </button>
{% else %}
    No button
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This time, it only displays the {% else %} part but the button after the else conditional doesn't work. I've updated the question. Please do have a look again. Thank you.

Comment: @jelly_bean why are you doing `{% if request.user.imagepath.image_path %}` just do `{% if request.user.path.path %}` according to your model

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake. The if/else conditionals work, but the buttons are not responding.

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you. The jQuery code was the issue.